# How to send http request using FormData in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, http, form-data

Here I want to send some data on my html form to the backend using angular HTTPClient server. I have used to try this code but not send my data to the backend server.

**HTML**

```
 <form class="border text-center p-5 reg-frm" [formGroup]="ContactusForm">
    <label>Full name :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control box_border" aria-describedby="textHelp"
                                    name="name" formControlName="name">
    <button (click)="sendMessage()" type="button"
        class="btn btn-info my-4 btn-block reg_btn ">Send Message</button>

 </form>
```

**TS File**

```
sendMessage(){
ContactusForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
})

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', this.ContactusForm.value.name)

this.http.post<any>(url, formData).subscribe(res => {
   console.log("data send");
});
}
```

Comment: any error being shown?

Comment: @Mridul No, no any errors, Not console log "data send".

Comment: @SachinMuthumala what was the console error you are getting?

Comment: Move ContactusForm fb.group declaration to ngOnInit. As per your code ContactusForm.name will be empty for all the times.

Comment: do not initialize `form` on button click. that's why your `name` value is not getting in `formData`

Answer (score 1):

This coding practice is not good,do not initialize formGroup inside sendMessage method, instead try this

At first use separate method to initialize form data, for this firstly import FormGroup and other necesssary things required, then declare a formGroup variable/property

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


//declare property
constactUsPayload: FormGroup;

//In Oninit- initialize payload.
ngOnInit(){
  this.initialize_payload();
}

initialize_payload() {
  this.contactUsPayload = this._fb.group({
    'name': this._fb.control('', Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]),
  });//you can declare more fields based on your future requirements
}

sendMessage(){
  this.http.post<any>(url, this.contactUsPayload.value.name).subscribe(res => {
    console.log("data send");
  });
}
```